# How to print summary of results for Multiple linear regression model (r2, etc) - Statsmodels vs SciKitLearn

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have the created a simple multiple linear regression model and would like to print the model summary - ei the OLS/regression summary.

However, I'm unsure if I should use scikitlearn or the statsmodels libraries as I found other posts/youtube videos that use both. Any explanation behind your choice would also be appreciated.

full code

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values


# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [3])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))


# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)


# Training the Multiple Linear Regression model on the Training set
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
predictions = (np.concatenate((y_pred.reshape(len(y_pred),1), y_test.reshape(len(y_test),1)),1))
```

df

```
    R&D Spend  Administration  Marketing Spend       State     Profit
0   165349.20       136897.80        471784.10    New York  192261.83
1   162597.70       151377.59        443898.53  California  191792.06
2   153441.51       101145.55        407934.54     Florida  191050.39
3   144372.41       118671.85        383199.62    New York  182901.99
4   142107.34        91391.77        366168.42     Florida  166187.94
5   131876.90        99814.71        362861.36    New York  156991.12
6   134615.46       147198.87        127716.82  California  156122.51
7   130298.13       145530.06        323876.68     Florida  155752.60
8   120542.52       148718.95        311613.29    New York  152211.77
9   123334.88       108679.17        304981.62  California  149759.96
10  101913.08       110594.11        229160.95     Florida  146121.95
11  100671.96        91790.61        249744.55  California  144259.40
12   93863.75       127320.38        249839.44     Florida  141585.52
13   91992.39       135495.07        252664.93  California  134307.35
14  119943.24       156547.42        256512.92     Florida  132602.65
15  114523.61       122616.84        261776.23    New York  129917.04
16   78013.11       121597.55        264346.06  California  126992.93
17   94657.16       145077.58        282574.31    New York  125370.37
18   91749.16       114175.79        294919.57     Florida  124266.90
19   86419.70       153514.11             0.00    New York  122776.86
```

Comment: `statsmodels` is the more statistically focused library so if inference is your main concern you'll likely want to use that, as it supports stuff like robust/clustered standard errors and tons of post estimation statistical tests. `sklearn` is more machine learning focused, so better if your goal is a model and then out of sample prediction. For a basic linear model estimated by OLS either will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no summary of an OLS model in `sklearn` you will need to use `statsmodel` and then call the `summary()` method on the output of the `OLS` model `fit()` method. You can see more in the docs [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/ols.html)

If you need R^2 for your `sklearn` OLS model you will need to use the `sklearn.meterics.r2_score` and pass it your predicted values to compare against the true values like so:

```
r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

With `y_true` being the true values of the data and `y_pred` being the predicted values from your OLS model. More info can be found on this method in the `sklearn` docs [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html)